# Error in proc export - Cannot delete worksheet cells

Tags: excel, sas, export

Iam using a proc export step to replace a sheet in my spreedsheet with new data.

```
PROC EXPORT data = work.filtro_segmentos2
    outfile = "myfolder/BASE_DIAG.done.xlsx"
    dbms = EXCELCS replace;
    sheet = "ANALÍTICO";
    SERVER  = "&IP_ADDRESS.";
    PORT = &PORTA.;
RUN;
```

but this error keeps happening:

```
ERROR: CLI execute error: [Microsoft][Driver ODBC Excel] Cannot delete worksheet cells.
WARNING: Table _IMEX_."ANALÍTICO$" has not been dropped.
ERROR: There was a problem removing the original table ANALÍTICO.  See Log for details.
```

I've done some research in SaS documentation and find this solution, but I dont know how to adapt to my needs(replace a whole sheet). A little experience as help would be great!

```
The first example sends data from a SAS session to an Excel spreadsheet. The target cells are rows 1 through 100 and columns 1 through 3. To send the data, submit the following program:

/* The DDE link is established using   */
/* Microsoft Excel SHEET1, rows 1      */
/* through 100 and columns 1 through 3 */
filename random dde
   'excel|sheet1!r1c1:r100c3';
data random;
   file random;
   do i=1 to 100;
      x=ranuni(i);
      y=10+x;
      z=x-10;
      put x y z;
   end;
run;
```

[SaS Documentation](https://%20https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/hostwin/n1aqiv6biqkjbnn1gu1388hp7aab.htm#n02156mkjuxkqzn19spmulfzuia6)

Thanks!

Comment: The example is wholly irrelevant, if you're using EXCELCS in particular you likely can't use DDE, and even if you could, you shouldn't as it is no longer supported (and hasn't been for a long time) by either SAS or Microsoft.  I'm afraid I don't know EXCELCS very well, so I don't know if it's possible or not - but first thing I'd try is make a brand new workbook then test deleting a worksheet there.   If you can, then there's something with the specifics of your case.  If you can't then it's probably not possible.

Comment: I've tried with another worksheet as you said and unfortunately it didnt work, maybe this is just not possible... I will try to design a way to update this sheet using microsoft acess. Thank u for Joe!